# Matrix colum headers in Monthly order

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm using a matrix and I would like my Month column headers to be in fiscal order...so April,May,June, July etc

I have looked at various answers about adding a calculated field but this only seemed to work for rows. I'm using Report Builder 3. Would appreciate some help please.

[image]

Comment: How are the months coming into the data set? Name or Number value? Can you show some sample data how it's coming into the report?

Comment: Hello, I am using this  datename(MM,DateCompleted)

Comment: I think you can try something with this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479697/how-to-specify-an-order-for-the-columns-in-a-matrix, to figure out a way to sort by the columns. If you can switch on the DateNames, starting with 1 for April and ending with 12 for March.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
=iif(datepart(DateInterval.Month, Fields!DateCompleted.Value) < 4, datepart(DateInterval.Month, Fields!DateCompleted.Value) + 12, datepart(DateInterval.Month, Fields!DateCompleted.Value))
```

This will add 12 to any month before April, making January month 13 and so on. Just use that in your sort order.